# How to modify functions in child theme wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I try a lot of things to modify in the child theme the function of some shortcodes but when I copy the functions that I want to modify in the file functions.php and that I modify what I want, no change is visible on my website.

thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DYLAN VURBIER Are you creating your own child theme directly from a parent theme, or are you modifying an existing child theme (i.e. trying to create a "grand-child" theme)?